# Mock auto-generated setter in Kotlin with Mockito

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
internal interface IRegisters {
    var i: Short
    var pc: Int
    var sp: Int
}
```

Now, when I compile that interface, the public fields are replaced by getters and setters. I suppose that the final result is not exactly this, but let's assume it is for simplicity sake:

```
internal interface IRegisters {
    fun getI(): Short
    fun setI(value: Short)
    fun getPc(): Int
    fun setPc(value: Int)
    fun getSp(): Int
    fun setSp(value: Int)
}
```

My problem is: with Mockito, I can mock the getter part the following way:

```
Mockito.`when`(registersMock.sp).thenReturn(16)
```

Which I suppose is replaced behind the scenes at some point in the compiling process for something like this:

```
Mockito.`when`(registersMock.getSp()).thenReturn(16)
```

I verified that this is in fact correct replacing the `.thenReturn` part for a `.thenAnswer`. The `invocation.method` while calling to the `answer` method of the answer was, indeed, `getSp`.

My question is: how do I mock (if it is even possible) the `set` counterpart?

I have tried this:

```
Mockito.`when`(registersMock.sp = ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()).then...
```

But it tells me that *assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context*. And, because the `setSp(value: Int)` doesn't exist yet, I can't do the following either:

```
Mockito.`when`(registersMock.setSp(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).then...
```

...as it gives a *unresolved reference* error (which is reasonable, as the behavior is consistent if I try the `getSp()` counterpart).

This is specially infuriating because I can **verify** the `setSp` method using the `=` assignment the following way:

```
Mockito.verify(
    registersMock,
    times(1)
).sp = 0x300
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took a while, but I found something working. The trick was to *swap* the `whenever` and the `doAnswer`.
For example I can extract the passed-in Int when the setter is called.
working solution:

### source code:

```
interface IRegisters {
 var sp: Int
}
```

### mock in tests:

```
val mockIRegister = mock<IRegister>()
var lastSp: Int? = null
doAnswer { invocation -> 
 lastSp = invocation.getArgument(0) as? Int
}
 .whenever(mockIRegister)
 .sp = anyInt()
```